# Handling Togglebutton ControlTemplate

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

If i use this code:

**Eyes on "Path" element**

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="ExpandCollapseButton">
                                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" Fill="#FFDBDBDB"/>
                                                <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                Data="M2,3L9,10 16,3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="6" Fill="#FFDBDBDB"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateButtonTransform"/>
                                    </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                </ToggleButton>
```

All shows just fine.

Example:

[image: Example]

But when i use whole code with animations, **the position is set to Left but it appears on right**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Expander">
<Style TargetType="local:Expander">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Expander">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.0"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid  Background="#FFDBDBDB" Margin="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" Canvas.ZIndex="2"/>
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="ExpandCollapseButton">
                                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" Fill="#FFDBDBDB"/>
                                                <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                Data="M2,3L9,10 16,3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="6" Fill="#FFDBDBDB"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateButtonTransform"/>
                                    </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="Content">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When i tap my expander the Path jumps from left to right - **where is the problem?**

Example:

[image: Tap1]

[image: Tap2]

When position is Center it shows correct

**ADDITION:**

If i delete animation x:Name="RotateButtonTransform" then Path element is being shown correctly - but i need this transform to rotate the Path

**ADDITION 2:**

Deleted togglebuttons animation, and added this lines:

To visual state storyboard:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotatePath"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
```

To Path element:

```
<Path.RenderTransform>
     <RotateTransform x:Name="RotatePath"/>
</Path.RenderTransform>
```

Code somewhy fails...

Error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `ToggleButton` spans across 2 columns and you set it `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` which means that `ToggleButton` will have a width of whole header and when you expand and apply 180 rotation that rotates around its centre and what was on the left side is now on the right side upside down. Change `HorizontalAlignment` on your `ToggleButton` to `Left` and that should solve your issue.

If you want to keep `ToggleButton` stretched then don't rotate button but `Path` inside it:

```
<ToggleButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.0"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" Fill="#FFDBDBDB"/>
            <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M2,3L9,10 16,3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="6" Fill="#FFDBDBDB">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateButtonTransform"/>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ToggleButton.Template>
```

Comment: Thanks, now i get the point, but i want to make it a long toggle button, which gets the width of the screen

Comment: so don't rotate `ToggleButton` but it's `Path` (set alignment to Left on that). Bind rotation to `IsChecked` property of `ToggleButton`

Comment: Logicaly, but can you look what is wrong with my path rotating? Added Addition 2 to my question

Comment: Error 4 The property 'Triggers' does not exist on the type 'ControlTemplate' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: I suppose it's because it's not WPF but Windows Phone. Try changing it to Visual States Checked/Unchecked (this should be available) like you did for Expander Expanded/Collapsed

Comment: @Cheese, I've updated my answer with use of VisualStates. Hope it will work on Windows Phone

Comment: Thanks, you saved me, now i will study your code to find out how you did it =)